# Can I drive stepper motor with AC voltage?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, driver, stepper-motor

I want to buy this motor
SANYO DENKI 103H7823-1741 for building my CNC

I have found the datasheet over [here](http://www.cnc-modellbau.net/shop-eng/files/sanyodenki-103h78231741.pdf)

in the [website](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/103h7823-1741/electric-motors/sanyo-denki/) that I will buy it from it says

**Motor: AC; stepper; 100VAC; step 1,8°; 2.7Nm; 1.34kg; 4A**

from what I know the stepper motors work with pulses but using DC voltage, so what does it mean to be rated with 100 VAC ?

***EDIT***

would it make difference if this motor was rated with DC voltage ?
Can I drive this motor with 24V DC(of course using stepper motor driver)?

Comment: I think that is just a way to say it is a bipolar stepper. You have to apply an alternating current to make it spin if you think about it. During each step you apply DC, but you are constantly reversing it as you spin, hence a H-Bridge is used.

Comment: but at the same website http://www.tme.eu/en/details/103h5208-5240/electric-motors/sanyo-denki/ there is other bipolor motor rated with DC voltage instead of AC, which makes a lot of confusion for me

Comment: It's not entirely clear which winding option you are being offered with that motor.  As to the general question, the simple-case output of an ideal microstepping driver is in fact two orthogonal AC phases, something other drivers only approximate.  There exist stepper motors which can be run synchronously from an AC line (or transformer reduced AC) with a phase shift capacitor for the second winding, but that's not necessarily what you are being offered.  For CNC you need a low impedance (typically signified by low rated voltage) winding to get good performance.

Comment: Can you mention an example for a low impedance motor, I mean tell me how low it should be to be considered as low in your opinion

Comment: @MuhammadNour - Try here http://www.mechapro.de/pdf/H7823-1710.pdf for instance. The motor is rated for 4 amps total, or 2 amps per winding. Winding resistance is listed as 0.65 amps each. So coil voltage is about 1.3 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motor specification in your second link is very badly wrong. The data sheet provided by the website page is for a 24 volt DC stepper motor, as shown on page 6. However, further down the data sheet a system diagram is shown which suggests the use of an AC to DC power supply with an input of 100 to 240 VAC - that is, just about any AC voltage you'll find in the world. So the description is badly misleading. Why they called it a 100 VAC stepper is impossible to say, but a major brain fart by whoever created the web page is a good bet.

The linked datasheet is correct, and as it states, the nominal operating conditions are 4 amps at 1.4 volts. That is, it's a bipolar stepper with 0.65 ohm windings and a nominal maximum of 2 amps per winding. In order to drive it, you would want a standard bipolar driver with that capability. If you apply 24 volts, unless the power supply is current limited to 2 amps you will burn out the motor.

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not.  Stepper motors are usually manufactured with a wide range of winding options in the same physical housing, and it's not clear which one the product actually being offered for sale will have.  There are even motors of this type wound with high impedance for synchronous operation from the AC mains using a capacitor to phase shift one winding.  Generally speaking a low voltage winding is preferred for a CNC machine, as it will have a lower inductance and so can achieve decent torque at high step rates wit a moderate driver voltage.

Comment: Even a 24 volt coil would be far too high for something that needs to work against cutting force and rapid from one position to another.  Instead, one wants something like a 4v coil, and a chopping current mode driver than can call on the potential of a much higher supply voltage (24v minimum, perhaps 50v or even 75v) to force rated current against the winding inductance when stepping rapidly.

Comment: The specific entry for that particular motor (actually 103H7823-1740) is on page 41 of the datasheet, and the specs match the ones on the web page, except for that 100VAC number.

Comment: @Chris Stratton why would a high voltage stepper motor wouldn't  be suitable for CNC machine, I imagine the more voltage it can handle the more torque at higher speed it would be able to achieve, right?

Comment: No, the less.  To get good high step rate performance, you want a motor rated for a low voltage (when not moving) and then you operate it with a chopping driver than can call on a far, far higher voltage to rapidly drive current against it when moving.  If the driver can only use the rated voltage, you'll quickly hit a commutation speed where you simply don't have time to develop a meaningful current when fighting that inductance.  The *insulation* rating of the winding is another matter - the usual nameplate rating is the voltage at which rated current is achieved *when a winding is left on*.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast you said the linked datasheet said 4AMPs @ 1.4 volts, have you meant this one http://www.cnc-modellbau.net/shop-eng/files/sanyodenki-103h78231741.pdf I actually can't find any 1.4 volts in any place in the file, would please point out which datasheet you are refering to.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast so you are saying the motor that I have referred to in my question (103H7823-1741) has a nominal voltage rated @ 1.4 DCV with 4 AMPS right?

Comment: @MuhammadNour - 2 amps each for two windings. 1.4 volts on each winding.

Answer (score -1):

These are voltages of power supply to the stepper driver, not the motor. You should look for stepper+driver characteristics. There are described characteristics for 24VDC and 100VAC driver + motor, that's the reason this data is in datashhet, but it doesn't mean anything. You can use DC or AC driver packs, as long the DC bus voltage doesn't exceed motor withstanding voltage. More voltage, more rpms. You do need a calc of max rpms you need.

I have mounted these motors with use of RTA drivers, I choosed DC drivers and I used the transformer and rectifier + capacitor circuits arround 50VDC (transformer 38VAC/250VA, Capacitor EPCOS B41560A8229M 22mF@63V) and inrush current limit circuit

Comment: thanks you for your answer, it just confusing me because at the same website there is other bipolar motors rated with DC voltage

Comment: Withstand voltage □42（□ 1.65inch）：AC500V 50/60Hz for 1 minute, □50（□ 1.97inch）・□56（□ 2.20inch）・□60（□ 2.36inch）：AC1000V 50/60Hz for 1 minute: these are important data, as you can see you may buy AC driver that goes direct on mains 230VAC, normaly I do use this type for OEM machines, but you may like more a DC PSU, it makes less noise. What are your max RPMs? Becasue you are looking at motor 75V/kRPM, means if you expect 1000rpms the DC bus voltage supply has to higher that 75V.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What are you talking about? These motors are made for CNC, I have installed lot of them. And yes the withstand voltage are for windings, not PSU - it is copied from manual and it is clear, therefore if it withstands 1000VAC it is suitable to use a driver with AC input 230VAC, or not?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - the same motor is typically offered with a wide range of windings options, and it is not clear which is being offered.  Only the lowest impedance options will be satisfactory in a non-trivial CNC application.  You may not be aware of it, but the range of windings for motors of this type can include those with sufficient impedance to be operated from the AC mains with a phase shift capacitor - 100 VAC is entirely plausible.  You really can't say if this motor is suitable without knowing exactly *which* of the winding options it will be delivered with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Where did you see a stepper motor on AC with capacitors? The motor wouldn't make a single turn  + a NC has to control it, sending pulses to the driver usually MOSFET, not capacitors and impedance,...

Comment: @ChrisStratton What inductivity is then suitable for CNC motor that you mention, in terms of real numbers Henries? This motor has 0.65ohm and 4A, meaning at standstill the coil voltage equals 2.6V.

Comment: The key to understanding is to realize that the output of an ideal microstepping driver is two orthogonal AC phases.  In legacy industrial applications where a high torque fixed low speed drive is needed, stepper motors with high voltage AC line coils were offered - I have  few at home, and they're useless for CNC given the inductance.  Better motor data sheets will specify the inductance, though pragmatically one can just shop for a low voltage rating as that typically implies low inductance.  To put it another way, you want a driver capable of delivering many times the rated voltage.

Comment: I asked in terms of Henries, ohms, volts, amperes,...not words. What stepper motor is suitable for CNC given the torque of 2.7Nm that OP is looking for CNC? Give a Sanyo Denki model, because Sanyo Denki are reputable motors for CNC.

Comment: That is not answerable, as you have not provided sufficient information.  You can calculate the maximum step rate at which full torque can be achieved (by delivering rated current) from the inductance and voltage available to the driver. Practically speaking, especially if shopping for a bargain you just look for a low voltage winding and a high voltage driver. Or if you don't mind paying a huge price premium, give their applications engineers a call.

Comment: I am now totally lost after reading all the comments and the answers, I have chosen this motor because it has a good torque over speed(pulses) and cost, currently I can't go beyond 48 volts for driving so ...., I really don't know

Comment: @MuhammadNour Why you can't go over 48VDC? You already have a 48V PSU? You didn't answer what are expected max rpms, with 48V you can't go over 640rpm, theoreticaly, practicaly even less, let's say 500rpm is maximum.

Comment: how did you calculate the speed?

Comment: I have said 48V because I don't have more for now and I may build the driver myself and I have for now mosfets that can stand only 55v

Comment: @MuhammadNour Do you at least have any driver's schematics that you think is going to work? Leadshine makes excelent drivers for reaonable price, I think you can't DIY for the same money.

Comment: I have most of the components actually, the mosfets, drivers, Arduino Due, and other logic glue stuff, don't have yet schematic but I have a good general idea about what I am going to do

Comment: @MuhammadNour Sorry to disapoint you, but I don't think that arduino is capable to make it a stepper motor driver, there are other dedicated MCUs for motor control like STM32, but I wish you good luck.

Comment: Arduino due have atmel arm cortex m3 with 96 mhz so I think it should be more than enough, anyway I have to try it myself

Comment: Just search on internet and you will see that no serious motor driver has this chip, there are only custom made processor for that. Ain't so simple as you think.

Comment: There are several seriously incorrect claims here.  First, ATmega Arduino derivatives are quite commonly used as stepper motor controllers - running as many as six coordinated axis in 3d printers.  Next, the given RPM calculation is entirely meaningless.  No meaningful calculation or motor recommendation is possible without knowing the load to be moved, acceleration required, etc.  About all that can be said is general guidelines like picking a low impedance winding and a driver with a high voltage available to fight the inductance.